# VS Code Snippets buggy since most recent update?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Is it just me or have VS Code snippets become horribly buggy since the most recent update? When you select one of your snippet propositions with a hit on tab, only half of it gets sometimes pasted. Not all snippet choices, but only 2 or 3 start showing up when you start typing a prefix (that is shared across like 10 of your snippets).

Anyone having the same issues? Just to check if this is due to VS Code update, as all of my snippet configs remain unchanged....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They seemingly fixed the issues; as the snippets behave normally again after the last update.